# what is the technique to process 1 million records from a database

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is more or less a design question. we have to process like a 1 million rows and send an xml to a third party. Initially we have to send like 1 million records, later we will send the deltas only.

Right now the stored procedure is taking approchimately around 15 to 20 min to return the  data. Its a consoleapp right. I know its not a good way to get 1 million records at time.

I want to know the following things
1) Is console app in c# which connects to database is right approach or not
2) Are there any other ways of doing this?

Appreciate your guidence on this , there is no need for any coding or so , We need some some advice on how to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1: Depends on your architecture. That simple. It is a VIABLE approach.

Re 2: Yes, tons. All vaible. You could make a system service handling data generation upon request. You could have a web application.

In general, a console app will work fine, and 1 million rows nia a result set are no exactly a lot either. Totally workable.

1-20 minuts is odd, though. Where is the time spent? 1 million rows to transfer and write out shoul not take more than 2-3 minutes.

Comment: its not a single table which has all the records, its a huge stored procedure which joins many tables and gets the data, i have one more question assuming all the data in one table , will there be any problem to get so much data ?? you think 1million records is ok.

Comment: I routinely deal with 500 million row sets, so... if you ahve the right hardware, it will be VERY ok.

Answer (score 4):

My thoughts:

- don't fetch all the data *then* process it; but process it *as it arrives* - via `IDataReader` or LINQ
- use equally streaming approach for the file; perhaps `XmlWriter` directly, or maybe `XStreamingElement` - in either case reading from the source above

this vastly reduces the amount of memory you need, and allows your machine to do something useful while waiting on the network IO

Comment: one more question , what happens if the stored procedure takes time to return the data.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yeah, why not.

2) Yes.

Use cursors.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be a little more specific on what you are doing during the 15 to 20 minutes.

You are asking about the "right" way to do things - what are you optimising for?

Speed?  A 15 - 20 minute stored proc sounds dangerous.  What is it doing?

Maintenance / Readability?  A console app will work.  It would also be easier to test (unit testing etc) than a stored proc.

I have never liked long running stored procedures because it's not easy to see progress.  At least with a console app you can output *something*

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, 1 million records isn't a big deal to a famous commercial data base, it's not worth 15 to 20 min to return the records. Somewhere else is wrong! Are you building the XML file in the store procedure? If yes, please remove them and implement the XML building in C#. The SP has only one simple task: fetching data. It won't take a long time if you are not joining 1 million records on another 1 million records. After the data come into the application(console application is ok in this case), build the XML with maybe LINQ-to-XML. If you are still not satisfy with the performance, make your code [parallel](http://aditiblogs.com/blog/blog/2009/06/07/parallel-programming-in-c-40-using-visual-studio-2010/).

**EDIT** Your SP is time consuming, you need to optimize it. An example: In the SP T_Data with 1m records joins T_User with 1m records that costs a lot of time. After optimization: In the SP T_Data joins one record in T_User(almost a WHERE expression which is very fast), and in C# code you are getting the records from T_User, for each record, call the SP and get the data, then build one *section*/*piece* of your XML. All of them can be processed concurrently. At last, you merge all the pieces of XML into one.

Comment: @Danny - re parallel - the OP is almost certainly blocked at both IO points (in and out); adding more CPU won't help that

Comment: @danny , the xml is generated in the console app only , the stored procedure has several joins and thats why it is taking so much time. I think according to all here , its ok to get 1 million records and process in the console app.

Comment: @gov - if the time is in the joins, add any appropriate indexes, denormalize, etc

Comment: @Marc: You are correct, since most of time are spent on JOINs.

Comment: @danny and marc, i will work with database team regarding the sp